# How to make a button that allows a WebGL model to go back to its initial orientation?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, grafana, fbx

I am building a plugin for [Grafana](https://grafana.com/). In this plugin, I load a model with a .fbx extension, using threejs, orbitcontrols and FBXLoader. The plugin gets data from Grafana and uses this to update the Roll, Pitch and Yaw of the model.

However, because I have added controls, it is possible to zoom in/zoom out or to look at the model from a different angle.

Now I want to create a button that gets the model back to its initial orientation when it is clicked on. I think I have to make a button that calls a function backToInitial() or something, and then this function has to change the position and rotation of the camera (so not from the model itself?) to its initial state. I have tried multiple things, but nothing has worked yet. I am having the most trouble with putting the button in the right place and adding an event listener that reacts when the button is clicked (because the html and js are in separate files).

Does anyone know if this idea is logical and how to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `THREE.OrbitControls()` has [`.reset()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/controls/OrbitControls.reset) method.

Comment: Thanks @prisoner849 for your comment! I have tried a lot of things to add this method into my code, but I cannot seem to find a way to make a nice button inside my WebGL model. If I try to make a normal HTML button, it appears on top of the scene, which is really ugly and the scene itself gets smaller to make space for the button. Do you know a way with which this does not happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're welcome :) You can create a new question with more details about the project you're working on. Add pics of what you have and what you want to achieve in the result. The more information you give, the quicker and more detailed an answer you get. It would be much better if you include a live code example.